# Black spots on new betta

Tags: betta

[image]
I just recently bought this White Opal Male Betta a few days ago. When I bought him I noticed some black spots/coloring on him and just want to be sure it is coloring not some type of bacteria or infection. There is one spot on his tail fin, a little bit by his mouth and some on his front fins. He seems very happy, likes to eat and is very active.  Are the spots something I should be worried about? [image]

Comment: did you not cycle the tank at all before you put the fish in the tank?,if not you need to read this https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm and you need to take water tests to monitor the water quality(look for ammonia and nitrite in the water,it is toxic to fish and you need to do large water changes if this is present)

Comment: @trondhansen Hi there! I did cycle the tank before I put the fish in. He had all these markings the day I bought him.

Comment: my comment was only ment as information,most petshops do not inform people about the need for cycling a tank.i can not answer your question but the spots on your fish do look like natural pigmentation of the skin.

Comment: Thank you @trondhansen Just purchased the correct water testing kit as well!